# Flutter ListView.builder keeps scrolling even if there are no more items

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

So I have 2 posts in the database...this code shows it very well.
The problem is the 2 posts takes only half the screen so no need to scroll any more.

But I can scroll and keep scrolling even after my posts are out of the screen view and don't show anymore my `ListView` keeps scrolling...I kept scrolling that I think I might reached the Earth's core.

I searched and found that everyone uses the same code for `ListView.builder` and it works fine with them..what is the problem ?.

```
void _scrollListener() {
  if (!_isLoading) {
    if (controller.position.pixels == controller.position.maxScrollExtent) {
      setState(() => _isLoading = true);
      getTopicPosts();
    }
  }
}
```

```
RefreshIndicator(
  child: ListView.builder(
    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
    controller: controller,
    itemBuilder: (context,int index) {
      if (index < postsWidgets.length) {
        return postsWidgets[index];
      } else {
        return Center(
          child: new Opacity(
          opacity:_isLoading? 1:0.0,
          child: new SizedBox(
            width: 32.0,
            height: 32.0,
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
  onRefresh: () async {
    if(!_isLoading) {
    postsWidgets.clear();
    lastVisible=null;
    await getTopicPosts();
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide `itemCount`

```dart
ListView.builder(
  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
  controller: controller,
  itemCount: postsWidgets.length, //this
  itemBuilder: (context,int index) {
      return postsWidgets[index];
```

Comment: it has stopped the scrolling but now the refreshing feature doesn't work since the user should have the ability to scroll up to refresh the posts and get new ones...now no scrolling at all....the bouncingScrollPhysics isn't working too for some reason

Comment: try to check from scaffold body